# How do I remove the most recent post from the sidebar in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, blogs, wordpress

On both the front page and the blog page - the sidebar shows the most recent post, which I find doesn't look very good duplicated against the same post expanded on the main page.

This is my code for the sidebar:

```
<div class="blog-sidebar">
<?php query_posts('showposts=5'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="blog-sidebar-feature">
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
            <div class="blog-sidebar-image"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title=""><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?></a></div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <div class="blog-sidebar-content">
            <p class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></p>
            <h3 <strong><?php

    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
echo $category->cat_name . ' '; 
    } 
    ?></strong></h3>
    <h2 <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title=""><?php the_title();         
    ?></a></p></h2><?php echo get_excerpt(166); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile;?>
<br />
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
</div>
```

and the relevant code for how the blog appears on the home page:

```
<div class="blog-sidebar">
    <div class="blog-sidebar-feature">
        <?php query_posts('orderby=date&order=DESC&showposts=2'); ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                <div class="blog-sidebar-image"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title=""><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?></a></div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <div class="blog-sidebar-content">
                <p class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></p>
            <h3 <strong><?php
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
echo $category->cat_name . ' '; 
    } 
    ?></strong></h3>
                <h2 <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"    
    rel="bookmark" title=""><?php the_title(); ?></a></p></h2><?php echo get_excerpt(166); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="connect">
    <?php query_posts('page_id=1');
      while (have_posts()): the_post();
      the_content();
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

Is there any way to remove only the most recent post from the sidebar when it appears in full on the main container? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE V2**

So you do want recent posts, just not the post currently showing in the main content.

**UPDATE V3:**

This should work now. I had to change arguments of `query_posts` to array to make it work.

Try it now:

```
<?
global $wp_query;
$skip_posts=array();
if (is_single()) //only exclude posts when single post is shown
$skip_posts[]=$wp_query->post->ID;
?>
<?php query_posts( array( 'showposts'=>5,'post__not_in'=>$skip_posts)); ?>
```

Comment: I assumed that the above code was in sidebar.php. Is it there or is it somewhere else?

Comment: Yes it's in sidebar.php. I tried your suggestion in both sidebar.php and home-template.php (where a featured latest blog post and sidebar posts also appear) but unfortunately it made the sidebar disappear in both.

Comment: Try replacing if statement with - if ( !is_front_page() && !is_home() )

Comment: Now I get it what you want. I updated the answer. Sorry for not understanding the first time:)

Comment: I missed the word "duplicated". Check the updated answer. Sorry. English is my second language.

Comment: I tested your sidebar code on my development site and added my code. I have modified the code a little so that now it works on my site without any problems. Try it now.

Comment: Perfect! What I'm going to do is put my offset code in home-template.php so the latest post doesn't feature in the sidebar on the home page, but put yours in sidebar.php so that once people have visited the blog (ie. navigated away from the front page), whatever post they are reading do not show up in the side bar. You've spent ages helping me with this, I really appreciate it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=5&offset=1'); ?>
```

Thanks to 850010 for all the help, I went back and had a look at the offset rule and the 'array' wasn't needed. Deceptively simple.

Comment: That code skips the latest post and does not really address your duplicate problem when you go to any older post as evident from 
http://av5theapiaryconz.avatar.net.nz/blog/upcycle/hexagonal-honeyjar-spice-rack/ - check my updated v3 code